# How to edit a template file in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, phtml

I am new in Magento2. I need to edit a already existing template file in magento2. For ex: I need to shipping.html in Magento_Checkout. I don't know where to edit this file, and moreover it is like .html file. But I want to edit phtml file of this.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: what is your current theme?

Comment: Emthemes/everything_default

Answer (score 6):

copy this file

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/shiping.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/fronted/Emthemes/everything_default/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/shiping.phtml
```

now make change here in your theme.

Comment: it is a generated .html file, not a phtml file

Comment: what is the file location? file path

Comment: i think you are talking about  static content  `pub/static/frontend/`. you cannot do changes there because when you deploy the new content all the changes in `shipping.html` file are replaced by new file generated from `hipping.phtml`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But there is no shipping.phtml. But when I make change in vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html, it is reflecting in front end. But I need to add a if condition here. Since it is a html file, I could not make it work. I need to know the phtml file of this.

Comment: But I need to add a if condition here. Since it is a html file, I could not make it work. I need to know the phtml file of this.

Comment: did you check with template file hints.

Comment: yes, it does not show any html file path

Comment: Good efforts taken to answer the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

`.html` file is not rendered content, it's [knockout templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html). So you can overwrite it in you theme witch {theme_root}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html file.